# Push C2DM notification Did not work

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I followed the same steps that are mentioned in the ["Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) - Tutorial"](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html), downloading the source code for the project and customizing it for my purpose (changing the package name and role e-mail sender).

Unfortunately I get an error message stating:

```
"Unable to start service Intent 
    {act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER ... }: not found" in logcat.
```

Knowing that I have added a Google account to the emulator which is different than the one I used when signing up on the service in the first place.

Can anyone provide help or direction in how can I get the registeration key correctly setup and solve this problem?

Comment: A "not found" error usually occurs when no REGISTER intent receiver is declared in the manifest, or the declared Activity is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figure the solution for my above question which is, you have to **create new AVD using android AVD manager that its target Google APIs either level 8 or 15 or whatever**, not using android API.
and also you have to have google account that added to your emulator which is the role e-mail that you used in development process of your application.

I hope that solve all problems faced other developers regarding this issue.